# could not build arguments for function: missing dependencies for function: missing type

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a Go server using Echo, but I'm stuck with this error. I can't figure out what the problem is here.

This is my code.

```golang
// internal/app/start.go
package app

func Start(di *dig.Container, cfg *infra.App, e *echo.Echo) (err error) {
    if err := di.Invoke(func(e *echo.Echo, hc HealthCheck, httpCtrl httpCtrl.HttpCtrl,
    ) {
        // Set route
        httpCtrl.HttpRoutes(e)
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

```golang
// internal/app/service/user.impl.go
package service

type (
  UserSvcImpl struct {
    dig.In
    NotificationsRepo   grpc.NotificationsRepository
  }
)

func NewUserSvc(impl UserSvcImpl) UserSvc {
  return &impl
}
```

```golang
// internal/app/repo/grpc/notifications.go
package grpc

type NotificationsRepository interface {
  SendNotifications(ctx context.Context, params models.Notifications) (err error)
}
```

```golang
// internal/app/repo/grpc/notifications.contract.go
package grpc

type (
  NotificationsRepositoryImpl struct {
    Registry grpc.RegistryGrpcConnection
    Client   packets.NotificationsClient
    Connected bool
  }
)

func NewNotificationsRepository(impl NotificationsRepositoryImpl) (r NotificationsRepository, err error) {
  return &impl, nil
}
```

The error itself happens on the last code on line  `func NewNotificationsRepository(impl NotificationsRepositoryImpl) (r NotificationsRepository, err error)`

This is the error code

```bash
FATA[0000] could not build arguments for function "github.com/project/user-svc/internal/app".Start.func1: 
failed to build service.UserSvc: could not build arguments for function "github.com/project/user-svc/internal/app/service".NewUserSvc: 
failed to build grpc.NotificationsRepository: missing dependencies for function "github.com/project/user-svc/internal/app/repository/grpc/activity".NewNotificationsRepository: 
missing type: grpc.NotificationsRepositoryImpl; close tcp [::]:30504: use of closed network connection
```

I don't understand why it's unable to detect the type. There's no compilation or syntax error, it only happens on runtime. Anyone knows why this happens?

I've been stuck with this error for days because I don't know why this error happens in the first place. It's just so weird that the type is considered missing. I've refactored the code but they also throw this error.

I also import other repository from the same package besides the `NotificationsRepositoryImpl`, and this error also happens to all of them too.